# insert images in 7 by 3 grid view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put images in a simple 7 X 3 table /grid view.

But I am not getting the desired result..
Probably I am looking at very wrong place.

I dont want to create a viewer or anything..

Just show the images in 7 X 3 grid view..

```
.floated_img
{
    margin-left: 10px
    width:140px; /* you can use % */
    height: auto;

}

<div class="floated_img">
    <img src="Picture1.png" alt="Some image">

</div>
<div class="floated_img">
    <img src="Picture2.png" alt="Another image">

</div>
....
```

Is there any template i can quickly download and use it to just put my images in it.

I have the images.. I just want to align them in a clean table view and just take a screen shot of it..

Comment: add float:left to your images, also apply a clearfix to the container of the floated divs

Comment: _"I just want to align them in a clean table view"_ - then why not use a table? No floating, no clearfix, no math, ...

Comment: @Andreas Because tables are for tabular data, not layout.

Comment: @cimmanon He just wants to make a screenshot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deal with table you can put your images in `LI`:

```
ul {
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14.28%; /* 100%/7 */
}
li img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NnrEv/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a floating solution check this http://jsfiddle.net/fSzxb/1/

```
.floater {
    float:left;
    ...
}
.floater.first {clear:both;}

/*clearfix*/
.cf:before,.cf:after {content: " "; display: table;}
.cf:after {clear: both;}
.cf {*zoom: 1;}
```

and your html

```
<div class="cf">
    <div class="floater first"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater first"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater first"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
</div>
```

Of course you can use some more semantic class names, instead of floater and cf

Comment: A very noob question. How do i insert an image here?

Comment: inside the `<div>` tags add an `<img>` tag. `<div><img src=""/></div>` or you could just add the `floater` class to the images and skip the divs altogether